# Exception Handing for Large Message Processing in BizTalk

Tags: exception, biztalk, large-files

My first ever stack overflow question, so please forgive any stupidity/naivety on my part here.

I have a BizTalk 2010 R2 solution that is using the [Claim Check](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html)
 integration pattern implemented with custom pipeline components to move large (currently up to 1Gb) .mp4 files to a folder location on receive and pick them up again on send so that they don't go through the BizTalkMsgBoxDb.

Occasionally we get an error in the receive of the files that leads to exceptions being raised in the receive port.  We use the 'Enable routing for failed messages' setting to avoid the instance suspending in the system, but this causes the large .mp4 file to be dragged into the message box and, ultimately, the EsbExceptionDb.  Obviously not the ideal solution.

I could implementent code in the custom receive pipeline component to deal with specific types of error but I do wonder whether there is a better way of handling this so that *any* exception - expected or unexpected - would result in the large file being routed to a failed file store elsewhere without entering the BizTalkMsgBoxDb at any time.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Does the custom pipeline component stream the file to disk, and replace `pInMsg.BodyPart.Data` with a stream containing a small XML message for further processing? Kind of like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180216/Transfer-Large-Files-using-BizTalk-Receive-Side)?

Comment: Yes it does pretty much exactly that.  The problem I'm trying to solve is when there is an error in that processing (for example, we recently had a network issue that made the target folder for stream write unavailable for a while) then the original file gets persisted to the message box as part of standard error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest handling exceptions in the custom receive pipeline.

Make absolutely sure `pInMsg.BodyPart.Data` gets replaced by a different (smaller) stream, then the big file cannot stream into the BizTalkMsgBoxDb because BizTalk does not have a reference to it any more.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to change it so that the msg.BodyPart.Data gets replaced straight away in processing, and custom exception handling within the pipeline component trys to stream the file to an error location.  I was hoping for a neater out-of-the-box solution, but I guess that is optimistic given we're already out of normal processing with a custom component.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have to use exception handling and make sure pInMsg.BodyPart.Data is not empty. Also if you are using custom pipeline as suggested in this article 'http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180216/Transfer-Large-Files-using-BizTalk-Receive-Side'

Please make sure you optimise the code in the execute method. For my case I replaced while while(bytesRead!=0) loop with below code. Now I do not see any issues in my custom pipeline and it works fast.
using

`(var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\Path\\To\\FileName")){originalStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);originalStream.CopyTo(fileStream);}`